# python Quick way to read formatted data from txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to find a best way to read array from text file, which is in format:

"filename.txt"

```
points = [
    [2.0, 0.0],
    [3.0, 2.0],
    [2.5, 2.0],
    [0.0, 1.5],
    [0.0, 0.0]
]
```

I know how to use `readline` to separate the data line by line, but are there simpler ways?

Answer (score 2):

If you will remove the 'points = ' from the file you will get a data structure that can be loaded using json.load()

```
import json

with open("my_file_after_cleanup.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

Comment: Your script could strip or just skip over it...which would eliminate having to change the file.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really python syntax, rename it to data.py and import it (or use importlib).
Using directly python syntax for datafile is one of the powerful features of python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data[data.find('=') + 1:]
    for remove_chr in ('\n', '\t', ' '):
        data = data.replace(remove_chr, '')
points = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(type(points).__name__, points)
```

output:

```
list [[2.0, 0.0], [3.0, 2.0], [2.5, 2.0], [0.0, 1.5], [0.0, 0.0]]
```